# How to apply data-jqmask to a textbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask

I'm trying to change the masked input of a text box using jQuery, using below code to change the attribute, but in output, I can see the only textbox without masked input like 111111111111111111111111, I want the output in the textbox like (000) 000-0000 0000000000, how can I achieve this

```
self.htmlFields.TXT_CONTACTNUMBER.attr('maxlength', '25');
self.htmlFields.TXT_CONTACTNUMBER.attr('data-jqmask', '(000) 000-0000 0000000000');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just updated the below code to get required output

```
self.htmlFields.TXT_CONTACTNUMBER.mask('(000) 000-0000 0000000000');
```